# insert images in database using controller

Tags: php, image, upload

i want to store images using controller.  with ifelse condistion,instead of storing them to db, the form shows the values passed to the variables in the browser. and    without ifelse condition, it throws:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtention() on null

here is the controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $register = new Register();

      $register->Name           =  $request->input('Name');
      $register->Last_Name      =  $request->input('Last_Name');
      $register->Associate_ID   =  $request->input('Associate_ID');
      $register->Address        =  $request->input('Address');

      if ($request->hasfile('image'))
      {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtention();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extention;
        $file->move('uploads/N_Registers/', $filname);
        $register->image =$filename;
      }
       else
       {
         return $request;
         $register->image='';


       }

      $register->save();

      return View('/home')->with('register'.$register);
```

Comment: My guess is that there is no file posted called `image`. That would explain both scenarios you've mentioned. If `$request->hasfile('image')` returns false in the posted code, the `else`-block will be executed and since it starts with a `return`, nothing after it will be executed (incuding the save). If you don't have the `if ($request->hasfile('image'))` at all and no file with that name is posted, then you'll get the above exception since `$file` then would contain `null` (it can't get a file that doesn't exist).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson.exactly. and i dont know the solution to avoid this ero as i m new to php nd laravel. so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to debug your code. We need more info. Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` and check what it actually contains. How are you sending the data? Please edit the question to include all the relevant HTML, JS and debug info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  how  can i perform(Do a var_dump($_FILES);) 
such operations?
i m supper new  to php

Comment: Start by adding all the relevant code to the question so we can see how the data is sent.